# Pre-painted Miniatures for D&D other than from Wizards

Tags: miniatures, dnd-miniatures-game

Are there substitutes for the official Wizards miniatures? Is there anything pre-painted that we can buy per lot?

We love them, but they are getting harder to buy. My group really values props and miniatures and praises for the fidelity of seeing the right mini for the monster.

Comment: Are you looking for actual minis, or are you okay with chips with pictures on them? Why are they harder to buy?

Comment: We are looking for real minis. WotC's minis are harder to buy due customs regulations in Brazil and because they are getting rarer as WotC releases few of them.

Comment: Are all minis going to have the same kinds of customs problems, or just WotC Minis?

Comment: Just WotC because it's Hasbro's. The custom's officials take it as children's toys and demands appropriate age indications from the Brazilian Test Institute (INMETRO).

Comment: Since this isn't a D&D 4e specific question you might consider removing the tag to get attention from those who don't look at 4e questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ordered some minis off rpglocker.com (Not affiliated with them in any way.)

Most of the stuff here is from Wizards, but you can buy them individually so you don't have to get an entire set for one character you want... The prices seem reasonable (about $1 per for most of them) and there was a pretty large selection.

Also, the guy was really easy to work with and kept me up to date on the status of the order. They're supposed to be here Friday, so I'd be more than happy to update you with the satisfaction of them then. I'm optimistic.

Comment: Mainly because they have good prices and international shipping.

Comment: Update: the minis came today, and I have no complaints :-)

Answer (score 6):

[Paizo and WizKids](http://paizo.com/paizo/v5748eaic9o2b) just announced pre-painted minis for Pathfinder.  Unlike the D&D minis, they're not randomized.  If you want to paint your own, there's always [Reaper Miniatures](http://www.reapermini.com/).

Answer (score 4):

There are pre-painted non-collectible plastic minis from [Reaper in their Legendary Encounters line](http://www.reapermini.com/LegendaryEncountersPre-paintedPlastics). Those, D&D Minis, and the upcoming Paizo/Wizkids minis are the most on point.

We also use Dreamblade, Horroclix, and other minis of that sort from WotC and WizKids - our group demands lots of minis and none of us have the time for painting and that kind of stuff.  Most of those are out of print though, and might be classified as games as well.  The bases are wildly inappropriate, usually taking up Large space at a minimum, but we get by.

For big lots, I mainly resort [to eBay](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw=D&D%20miniatures%20lot&_sacat=0&_odkw=D&D%20miniatures&_osacat=0&_trksid=p3286.c0.m270.l1313). Not sure if customs will look at them differently if sold used from a random dude or not.

Answer (score 1):

New stores crop up online with Wizards figs quite a bit, but another option might be to search for WizKids Mage Knight figurines and rebase them with 1" bases.